# JPA can not set Long field to Long

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I guess that I have a mistake somewhere...
It's supposed that 1 player has 1 stats table (oneToOne)

Class Player:

```
@Component
@Entity
@Table(name = "player")
public class Player {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "uid", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private Long uid;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "player", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private Stats stats;
    ....
```

Class Stats:

```
@Component
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Table(name = "stats")
public class Stats implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "player_uid", referencedColumnName = "uid", nullable = false)
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private Player player;
    ....
```

Class PlayerDAO:

```
public interface JPAPlayerDAO extends JpaRepository<Player, Long> {
    Player findByUid(Long uid);
    Player findByName(String name);
}
```

If I do this, it's fine:

```
Player p = new Player();
p.setUid(123L);
p.setName("Mike");
updater.saveOrUpdatePlayer(p);
p = playerDAO.findOne()
```

If I try to find it by name or uid, I get an error:

```
Player p = new Player();
p.setUid(123L);
p.setName("Mike");
updater.saveOrUpdatePlayer(p);
p = playerDAO.findByName("Mike")
or
p = playerDAO.findByUid(123L)
....
Caused by: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field ...entities.Player.uid to java.lang.Long
```

I think that it could be something wrong with my oneToOne reference.

Comment: If I remove a ref. from stats to uid @JoinColumn (name = "player_uid", referencedColumnName = "uid"), all works well. But I need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I remove a ref. from stats to uid @JoinColumn (name = "player_uid", referencedColumnName = "uid"), all works well.

If this is the case, the problem can be with the association as you already mentioned.
According to the JPA specification, support for mapping on non-primary key is optional, which means it must not be supported:

## 11.1.25 JoinColumn Annotation

...

> If the referencedColumnName element is missing, the foreign key is assumed to refer to the primary key of the referenced table.
>
> Support for referenced columns that are not primary key columns of the referenced table is optional. Applications that use such mappings will not be portable.

So you should change the annotation to:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "player_uid", referencedColumnName = "id")
```

or remove the `referencedColumnName` because the provider will use the default which is the primary key (in this case `id`).

Comment: If so, I think that I'll remove id from Player, then will use uid as @id and will bind Stats to this uid. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, important is that you make that field to be the primary key of the `Player` entity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need implementation of PlayerDAO here. You could try something like this

```
@Repository    
public interface JPAPlayerDAOImpl extends JPAPlayerDAO, JpaRepository<Player, Long> {

    @Override
    @Query("SELECT player FROM Player player WHERE player.uid =:uid")
    Player findByUid(@Param("uid") Long uid);

    @Override
    @Query("SELECT player FROM Player player WHERE player.name =:name")
    Player findByName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

PlayerDAO would look like this then:

```
public interface JPAPlayerDAO {
   Player findByUid(Long uid);
   Player findByName(String name);
}
```

Comment: JPAPlayerDAO uses a Spring Data repository interface, so the implementation is automatically created.